# Google Sheets Line Chart: adjust horizontal axis limits to exclude missing cells

Tags: google-sheets, axis

I noticed that the horizontal axis fits X values even if the corresponding Y-values are missing.
Is there a way to automatically adjust horizontal axis limits to exclude missing cells?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X3BhDyideX-7kyJ9Y-7xvV1naAwWd9eDPfPy3pP94Ic/edit?usp=sharing (sheet "Horizontal Axis Limits")

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Data > Filter** to hide blank rows. They will automatically be left out of the chart.

Alternatively, create a new data table that omits the blanks, like this:

`=query(A1:B, "where B is not null", 1)`

Then set the chart's data range to the new table.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, what can I do if I have other Y-columns filled with the data (see the sheet)?

Comment: I updated the sheet. Please check it out.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).